# input[type=file] slow to populate

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, file-upload

In Chrome (37), Firefox (31) and Internet Explorer 11 the first time I open a file using the file input;

`<input type="file" name="test" />`

there is a significant delay before the file name is shown on screen. Using IE9/10 the file name is shown instantly as is also the case when the file input is used additional times with the other browsers.

[Example - JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/58bsahtm/)

Is there a reason for this change of behaviour, and can it be fixed?

Comment: Not happening on my computer, Chrome 37

Comment: I also have this problem. I use Chrome 51.
but ie is ok.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the reason. I am not sure if the solution can be applied for you.
The pop up dialog go slow because I choose a network path for the previous file upload or a path that no longer exist. so if you choose a file on the local disk. Next time, The problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of cache. Try enabling cache as shown in the attached screenshot:

[image]

Comment: When using a screenshot like this to show the absence of a checkmark it would be wise to point that out clearly in the text, and maybe even mark up the image.